# Bourne Shell Array

Tags: backup, scripting, shell

I'm looking to write a bourne shell which loops through an array of hosts and performs an rsync for each.   Something like:

```
HOSTS=("host1.domain.com", "host2.domain.com")

for HOST in $HOSTS
do
    HOST_DIR_NAME = ${HOST//./-}
    rsync backup_user@$HOST:/backup/blah/blah /backup/$HOST_DIR_NAME/blah/blah
done
```

The issue is, however, it appears that the array above is not working as expected, as upon looping through the array I see the following output:

```
wwcprod.plyinc.com,
```

Every online guide I find says that I'm defining the array correctly, but its obviously not working.  Help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ideal solution is far simpler than a bash array (and far more portable to non-bash bourne-style shells):

```
HOSTS="one two three four"
for H in $HOSTS ; do
    [... whatever for ${H} ...]
done
```

The `for` will split on whitespace within a string :-)

Comment: Thank you!  Also, just so that I know how -- how would I correctly define an array of strings?

Comment: I'm pretty sure your array definition syntax is correct above, but the elements need to be addressed the same way C-style arrays are (not sure if you can `for` over them the way you're trying to or not - looks like you'd need a perl-style `foreach` kind of construct).  I don't do much bash-specific stuff personally because I try to keep things portable, but http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html seems like a good reference

Comment: Because you can iterate over whitespace or newline seperated values you hardly ever need an array in BASH. When you do need a more complicated structure you often end up having requirements that favor something like Perl or Python. To iterate over a BASH loop I usually use a C style for loop with a counter, but it can also be done with "for HOST in ${HOSTS[@]}; do echo ${HOST}; done".

Answer (score 1):

You must use `@` or `*` to access items in an array (info buried, as usual, in the [bash documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays)):

```
HOSTS=(host1.domain.com host2.domain.com)

for HOST in ${HOSTS[@]}
do
    HOST_DIR_NAME=${HOST//./-}
    rsync backup_user@$HOST:/backup/blah/blah /backup/$HOST_DIR_NAME/blah/blah
done
```

Using commas as item separator is wrong and quoting is meant to protect against spaces and shell expansion. Spaces are also significatives: `HOST_DIR_NAME = ...` expects a command named `HOST_DIR_NAME` and lauches it with `= ...` as arguments while `HOST_DIR_NAME=...` is an assignment.

I must also disagree with some previous comment: I often need to use arrays in Bash because of file names with spaces.